# unable to sync the selected radio button with apex contoller

Tags: apex, error, dynamic-visualforce, platform-bug

I have created a visualforce page :

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactMergeSelectionController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:actionFunction name="handleRadioSelection" action="{!handleRadioSelection}" rerender="tempp">
            <apex:param name="selectedColumn" assignTo="{!selectedColumn}" value="" />
            <apex:param name="selectedField" assignTo="{!selectedField}" value="" />
        </apex:actionFunction>
        <style>
        .firstRow {
            background-color: lightgrey;
        }
        </style>
        <apex:pageBlock id="tempp">
            <apex:outputPanel id="selectedValuePanel" style="margin-top: 10px;">
                Selected Value: {!selectedColumn} , Selected field: {!selectedField}
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable onRowMouseOver="this.classList.remove('highlight')" value="{!filteredData}" var="con" width="100%" rowClasses="odd,even" styleClass="tableClass" border="1px" cellpadding="8px" id="table">
                <apex:column value="{!con.fieldName}" headerValue="" styleClass="{!IF(con.rowNumber == 1, 'firstRow', '')}"/>
                <apex:repeat value="{!con.fieldValue}" var="temp">
                    <apex:column headerValue="" styleClass="{!IF(con.rowNumber == 1, 'firstRow', '')}">
                        <div style="width: 250px; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; ">
                            <apex:outputText value="{!temp[1]}">
                                <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!temp[1] != '[Empty]' && con.rowNumber != 1}">
                                    <input type="radio" name="{!con.fieldName}" onclick="handleRadioSelection('{!temp[0]}','{!con.fieldName}')" value="{!temp[1]}" />
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                            </apex:outputText>
                        </div>
                    </apex:column>
                </apex:repeat>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>            
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <div style="text-align: center;">
            <apex:commandButton value="Merge" action="{!mergeSelectedContacts}" />
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and a function for selection of radio button as:

```
public String selectedField { get; set; }
public Integer selectedColumn { get; set; }
Map<String, Integer> contactFieldValueMap = new Map<String, Integer>();

public void handleRadioSelection() {
        //selectedRadioValue = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('selectedRadioValue');
        String fieldc = selectedField;
        Integer selectedColumnc = selectedColumn;
        System.debug('field : '+fieldc+' col: '+selectedColumnc);
        contactFieldValueMap.put(fieldc,selectedColumnc);
        System.debug('size'+contactFieldValueMap.size());
        // Handle the selected value as needed
    }
```

But when I am selecting the radio button fastly then out of 18 selected button only 6 are inserted in the map, but if I patiently select the radio button in the interval of 2 secs then its working perfectly.

And In my debug I am getting correct values but when I am putting it in Map/List/Node it is not working(I have tried with list and node also)

I am not able to figure out why it is working like that.